# AngularJS - Attach Alert Popup to Empty Input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to configure my app to show an alert when the user tries to submit a form with an empty input box, but can't get it working even though I've a confirmation popup elsewhere in the same application.

Any ideas why this code might not be working?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpjgJJ.

JS:

```
$scope.addTask = function() {
        if ($scope.taskName.length == "") {
            $scope.showAlert = function(ev) {
                $mdDialog.show(
                    $mdDialog.alert()
                        .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#popupContainer')))
                        .clickOutsideToClose(true)
                        .title('Error')
                        .textContent('You must enter a task name')
                        .ok('Close')
                        .targetEvent(ev)
                )
            }
        }
```

HTML:

```
<form class="md-padding">

  <div layout-gt-sm="row">

  <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>

    <label>Add New Task</label>

    <input type="text" ng-model="taskName" size="50">

  </md-input-container>

</div>

<md-button ng-click="addTask()" class="md-raised md-primary">Add</span></md-button>
```

Comment: Why not use required attribute?

Comment: I'm trying to configure it to use the alert message, which wouldn't automatically appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your demo and made it work. Please check this [working demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZLVgR). You had a couple of problems in your code: e.g. try to load unkown ressources, use of undefined variables and wrong operations like `$scope.taskName.length == ""`. Finaly your code works:

```
if (angular.isUndefined($scope.taskName) || $scope.taskName.length === 0) {

    var alert =  $mdDialog.alert()
        .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#popupContainer')))
        .clickOutsideToClose(true)
        .title('Error')
        .textContent('You must enter a task name')
        .ok('Close');

    $mdDialog.show( alert )
        .finally(function() {
            alert = undefined;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is not working is because in this line:

`$scope.taskName.length == ""`

`taskName` variable in your scope is never initialized (even with an empty value) if that field was not modified by user.

Some recommendations:

1. Create a `task` object in your `$scope`:

`$scope.task = {}`

2. Change your input declaration to `<input type="text" ng-model="task.name" size="50">`
3. `$scope.taskName.length == ""` looks weird, use `$scope.taskName.length === 0`